# How to show based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make something which shows one of two divs based on the selection of a radio button. In terms of radio buttons I have this code:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-269" value="Purchase Only" />
<input type="radio" name="radio-269" value="Sale Only" />
<input type="radio" name="radio-269" value="Purchase and Sale" />
```

Then my DIV:

```
<div id="purchaseandsale" class="hidden" style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; background-color: grey;">
Purchase and Sale
</div>

<div id="purchaseorsale" class="hidden" style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; background-color: grey;">
Purchase or Sale
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
<script>
$("select[name='radio-269']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Purchase and Sale") {
       $('#added_fields').removeClass("hidden");
    }
    else {
        $('#added_fields').addClass("hidden");
    }
});
</script>
```

Firstly, it doesn't work and doesnt give me an errors in console. How can I also get it show me the purcahseorsale div if "purchase" or "sale" radio button is shown?

Comment: where is `<div id="added_fields">` ?

Comment: The selector should be input[name='radio-269']. This isn't a select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be referring to `input[name='radio-269']` instead of `input[select='radio-269']`.

Also, your ID selectors don't match those of the actual DOM.

The JavaScript should  be:

```
$("input[name='radio-269']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Purchase and Sale") {
       $('#purchaseandsale').removeClass("hidden");
    }
    else {
        $('#purchaseandsale').addClass("hidden");
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "Purchase Only" || $(this).val() == "Sale Only") {
       $('#purchaseorsale').removeClass("hidden");
    }
    else {
        $('#purchaseorsale').addClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

Check this JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MrXenotype/ZpP7f/

Comment: You can remove ifs by using `toggleClass( className, switch )`. http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/ZpP7f/1/

Comment: Ah, true, but I wrote mine that way to allow for more flexibility in case the user wanted to add more controls or scripts. Yours is more efficient in this case, but I was being more generic. :)